# Output cant be saved to file

Tags: python, bash

I am writing a small python script, where I also want to execute some bash commands by using *os.opopen()*. I want to save the output to file but it is not working. I have used the ">" before and it always works.
My code:

```
curl https://r2---sn-4g5e6ne6.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?key=yt6&txp=5432432&mime=video%2Fwebm&pl=16&source=youtube&gir=yes&signature=6A07D1659991EC9A570BC6A0E9C10FB54E743DBC.DA7798D03282620987FC2FBDB020D3FE464851F3&fvip=2&requiressl=yes&sparams=aitags%2Cclen%2Cdur%2Cei%2Cgir%2Cid%2Cinitcwndbps%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Ckeepalive%2Clmt%2Cmime%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cpl%2Crequiressl%2Csource%2Cexpire&ei=sTFcXPqmN9PlgAeN6ZiYCQ&itag=247&ipbits=0&mm=31%2C26&mn=sn-4g5e6ne6%2Csn-i5heen7l&c=WEB&id=o-AHSObPeCuNcs7m1xagNdnC7zcHOvQEKkCrV9NDTw7g7a&initcwndbps=1722500&ip=132.187.12.151&clen=64580535&mt=1549545753&mv=m&dur=561.594&ms=au%2Conr&keepalive=yes&expire=1549567506&aitags=133%2C134%2C135%2C136%2C137%2C160%2C242%2C243%2C244%2C247%2C248%2C278&lmt=1541003190670111&ratebypass=yes > test.bin
```

The bash command on its own works as expected.

Python command that I use:

```
os.popen("curl "+url+" > "test.bin") #url predefined
```

Any ideas where the problem could be?

Comment: what have you tried? what is the python code? have you read the docs for the subprocess module?

Comment: Yes, I have an idea... I bet it is in your python code. The one you talk about but don't show for us to help :-( The curl invocation that you show is working, right?

Comment: If you are running this with Python, please post that code. This is bash - if you are running this line of bash alone, please remove the Python tag.

Comment: sorry guys, in the rush I have posted just the bash code I will update

Comment: Quote your URL, it contains the `&` character which sends a job to the background: `curl 'https://www.example.com?a=b&c=d'`

Comment: But you say "the Bash command on its own works as expected", which is *not* what I'd expect.

Comment: @BenjaminW. the quotes remark was a good one, but I overreacted when I thought that it will solve the problem. It now doesnt show the output in the terminal, but it is still not saved to a file

Comment: Have you tried running this command in a terminal shell, without Python? I suspect this isn't a Python problem.

Comment: yes I have.. in the terminal it works... when I execute the command on its own it works, but when I try to save the output it stopped. The reference from Benjamin was a good one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In recent versions of Python, [`os.popen()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/os.html#os.popen) is just a wrapper for `subprocess.Popen()` which merely *starts* a process.

You probably want

```
from subprocess import run
with open('test.bin', 'wb') as bin:
    run(["curl", url], stdout=bin, check=True)
```

[`subprocess.run()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) is a higher-level wrapper which takes care of running the subprocess to completion and properly waiting for it to finish, etc. which `Popen()` and thus `os.popen()` does not do.

For more details, see also [Running Bash commands in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256107/running-bash-commands-in-python/51950538#51950538)

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code, I believe you have an unnecessary " in your code before the file name and the python reads test.bin as a variable, not a string in os.popen...

```
os.popen("curl "+url+" > test.bin")
```

This works for me, I hope it helps :)